# Ruby on Rails new() method not storing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a modified copy of https://github.com/talho/openphin/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/invitations_controller.rb

The main code is primarily the same, however our system was upgraded a few months back to Rails 4.x and the invitation system no longer works.

The method with the issue is create. I have tried swapping out:

```
@invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
```

with

```
@invitation = Invitation.create(invitation_params)
```

And creating

```
def invitation_params
    params.require(:invitation).permit!
end
```

However, here is what I have:

invitation_params = {"name":"Test","subject":"test","body":"test","organization_id":"","author_id":24448}

@invitation = {"id":null,"name":null,"body":null,"organization_id":null,"author_id":null,"subject":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"lock_version":0}

Also, if I use create!, then my output error is:

```
E, [2015-12-14T13:03:38.664099 #24385] ERROR -- : Validation failed: Author can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

I could use any guidance/help on why everything ends up as null.

Comment: It sounds like author_id is not included in the params[:invitation] hash. Is this property whitelisted in your controller (probably in a method called invitation_params)? And are you sure that the author_id is being passed from the previous action or view?

Comment: Yes. It is present when I output params[:invitation]. Just not being set for some reason.

Comment: I think I would need to see the controller code and the view template that is passing in the params[:invitation] hash that you are referencing in order to help effectively. For one thing, just the fact that you have hashes being returned with strings for keys rather than symbols, and null instead of nil, is completely different than what I expect from a Rails params hash and object.

Comment: The application is a modified version of a github repo that isn't being supported any longer. I have included relevant links below. Honestly, I don't even know why this code is no longer working and acting as it is now.

Controller: https://github.com/talho/openphin/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/invitations_controller.rb

View: https://github.com/talho/openphin/tree/04386fa080dae8921966344af33353fa62558970/app/assets/javascripts/invitations

Comment: Has this app recently been upgraded to Rails 4.x?

Comment: We updated to 4.0.2 about 6 months ago.

Comment: Ahh, yeah check out spickerman's answer below about using Strong Parameters then. Basically just his last chunk of code. In Rails 4, you need to whitelist parameters that are passed in from forms using a method like his invitation_params. Then from the action, use Invitation.new(invitation_params). Rails 4 doesn't allow you to just use Invitation.new(params[:invitation]) without you telling it what properties are permitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97901/discussion-between-shawn-dibble-and-michael-cruz).

Answer (score 2):

You call `return` what leaved the method, before you call `save!` in the record. Furthermore you might want to read about [Strong Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html). You might want to change your code to:

```
@invitation = Invitation.new(
  params.require(:invitation).permit( 
    :name, :subject, :body, :organization_id, :author_id
  )
)
@invitation.save!

render :json => { :invitation => @invitation }.as_json
return
```

Please note that you usually do not need to call return in controller method. And when you call `save!` immediately after `new` then `create!` might be an better option:

```
def create
  invitation = Invitation.create!(invitation_params)
  render json: { invitation: invitation }.as_json
end

private

def invitation_params
  params.require(:invitation).permit( 
    :name, :subject, :body, :organization_id, :author_id
  )
end
```

Comment: The render/return bit was just so I could output and see what was in params[:invitation] and what was being set in the created invitation. I also tried to change my code to yours, however when I render invitation, I still get null for all of my values. Here is my output:

{"invitation":{"id":null,"name":null,"body":null,"organization_id":null,"author_id":null,"subject":null
,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"lock_version":0}}

Comment: The line `Invitation.create!(invitation_params)` would raise an exception if Rails wasn't able to save the record. Therefore the record must be valid and saved, since there was no exception (otherwise you wouldn't be able to return json). Can you please update your question with your latest version?